# Do any Waco aircraft have model names?

Tags: aircraft-manufacturer, biplane

Many aircraft manufacturers give names to the aircraft models. Piper had the Cub, Super Cub, and all the Comanche/Cherokee/Navajo/etc. names used in branding. Cessna has the Skyhawk, Skylane, etc.

Did Waco aircraft use anything other than the three-letter names for branding?

**Edit:** I am wondering about the original WACO aircraft, not the company that produces reproductions today.

Answer (score 4):

Waco Aircraft was originally called "Weaver Aircraft Company of Ohio" in 1919. The first Weaver Aircraft Company aircraft was the 1920 "Cootie" but was it also called the "Waco Cootie". It was a monoplane that crashed on it's first flight and then rebuilt as a biplane.

The aircraft designs were called "Waco" as in "Waco 9" "Waco 10" even though the company became "Advance Aircraft Company" in 1923. In 1929 the name was formally changed to "Waco Aircraft Company".

The last Waco production aircraft design was the E Series "Aristocrat" biplane. There was also one prototype Model W "Aristocraft" which was a pusher prop, monoplane.  All the other Waco types had model designations consisting of letters and numbers, or military designations.

Comment: I wonder why this answer escaped any u-votes (or at least didn't gain a net score above zero) ever since 2-18-19?

Answer (score 1):

Waco does have a model called [Great Lakes](https://www.wacoaircraft.com/great-lakes-by-waco).

See also: [Wikipedia: Great Lakes Sport Trainer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Lakes_Sport_Trainer)

Comment: Good point! I was actually thing more about the original WACO company, which didn't produce the Great Lakes. I'll update the question.

Comment: Down voted because the "Waco Great Lakes" is not a Waco design. Great Lakes is the name of an aircraft manufacturer who produced many different types of aircraft.   The "Waco Great Lakes" is an updated reproduction of the original Great Lakes 2T-1A-2.

Comment: Hi @MikeSowsun: It doesn't deserve a DV in my opinion, the answer was posted before that clarification was made into the question. A simple note would suffice, but the asker already commented on that.